# JavaScript closure loop issue in set time out

Tags: javascript, closures

I've found some example in a tutorial (said it was the canonical example)

```
        for (var i=1; i<=5 ; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("i: " + i);
        }, i*1000);
    }
```

Now, I understand that, closure passes in the current scope in to the function, and I assume that it should output 1,2,3,4,5. But instead, it prints number 6 five times.

I ran it in the chrome debugger, and first it goes through the loop without going in to the function while doing the increment of the i value and only after that, it goes in to the inner function and execute it 5 times.

I'm not sure why its doing that, I know, the current scoped is passed in to the function because of closure, but why does it not execute each time the loop iterate?

Comment: This is because you are updating the value of `i` in for loop. By the time your timeout function is executed, the value of `i` is 6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. I couldn't get my head around the fact that inner part is acting a bit separately.

Answer (score 3):

By the time the timeout runs, the `for` loop has finished, and `i` is 6, that's why you're getting the output you see.  You need to capture `i` during the loop:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5 ; i++) {
    (function(innerI) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("i: " + innerI);
        }, innerI*1000);
    })(i);
}
```

This creates an inner function with it's own parameter (`innerI`), that gets invoked immediately and so captures the value of `i` for use within the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't want the complex-looking IIFE as explained in James' answer, you can also separate out the function using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function count(i) {
    console.log("i: " + i);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(count.bind(this, i), i * 1000);
}
```

Comment: This will also avoid the likes of jslint complaining about creating functions inside loops.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you  help,
I found out another solution and it was a minor change.

On the top of the page I turned on the strict mode and also in the for loop, Instead of var, I used the "let" keyword.